# How to do Autocomplete search to jquery chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

HTML

```
<select class="chosen" id="company_master" name="company_master" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
   <option>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I have tried following way but it does not work:

```
$('div#company_master_chosen>div>div input').keyup(function(){
        console.log("hi");
        var keyword = $(this).val();
        alert(keyword);
});
```

I want do Autocomplete search in jquery chosen search box with jquery ajax,  how to do? How to autocomplete perform in jquery chosen plugin..

Comment: Please include further example. If you're looking to do a search, you'll need an `<input>` element and you will want to initialize this in jQuery with `$("selector").autocomplete();`, but I am not seeing these elements. Please clarify what is not working.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on how to do this. Please see: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4Lojj5uq/

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-item ui-widget">
  <label>Select Company:</label>
  <select class="chosen custom-combobox" id="company_master">
    <option></option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-item {
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial, san-serif;
}

.form-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.form-item label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.form-item .custom-combobox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-item .custom-combobox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-item .custom-combobox-input {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 380px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $("<span>")
        .addClass("custom-combobox")
        .insertAfter(this.element);

      this.element.hide();
      this._createAutocomplete();
      this._createShowAllButton();
    },

    _createAutocomplete: function() {
      var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

      this.input = $("<input>")
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .val(value)
        .attr("title", "")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,
          source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
        })
        .tooltip({
          classes: {
            "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
          }
        });

      this._on(this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },

        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
      });
    },

    _createShowAllButton: function() {
      var input = this.input,
        wasOpen = false;

      $("<a>")
        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
          },
          text: false
        })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
        .on("mousedown", function() {
          wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          input.trigger("focus");

          // Close if already visible
          if (wasOpen) {
            return;
          }

          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
          input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    },

    _source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
          return {
            label: text,
            value: text,
            option: this
          };
      }));
    },

    _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

      // Selected an item, nothing to do
      if (ui.item) {
        return;
      }

      // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
      var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
      this.element.children("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
          this.selected = valid = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // Found a match, nothing to do
      if (valid) {
        return;
      }

      // Remove invalid value
      this.input
        .val("")
        .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
        .tooltip("open");
      this.element.val("");
      this._delay(function() {
        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
      }, 2500);
      this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
    },

    _destroy: function() {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
    }
  });

  $("#company_master").combobox();
});
```